# vivado HLS or SDsoc for use openCV

Tags: vhdl, c++, imageprocessing, zynq, vivado-hls

I want to do an image processing by openCV on FPGA . But I do not know if I should use the SDsoc method or the vivadoHLS method. The size of the images I am going to process is large and I want to solve the problem through parallel processing. What are the differences between SDsoc and vivado HLS? Which method is suggested to get the job done faster? .I want to use one of the cheap Zynq-7000 FPGAs.

Comment: `Which method is suggested to get the job done faster?` ... what is the job?

Answer (score 0):

> Which method is suggested to get the job done faster?

The best way to answer this question would be to simulate the problem and try it on different hardware in the simulation. Usually speed is a tradeoff with utilized resources on an FPGA because the faster things need to get done, the more digital hardware gets paralleled.